# Can I convert callback to promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, promise

I found this example:

Callback:

```
getDetails('Bob', function (err, details) {
   console.log(details)
});
```

To Promise:

```
getDetails('Bob').then(function (details) {
   console.log(details);
});
```

[example callback to promise](http://stuk.github.io/promise-me/)

but not work for me.

How do I convert callbacks to promises in javascript or angularjs?

Thanks!

Comment: before giving link, describe a little bit more.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Should show what the function getDetails does first as well as explain what you are wanting to do at a bit higher level. If `getDetails` returns a `$resource` for example then you would need to work with the documented `$resource` api and actually provide 2 callbacks

Answer (score 2):

```
getDetails('Bob').then(function (details) {
   console.log(details);
});
```

This work only if getDetails return a promise. To create a promise you need $q service.

So getDetails should looks like:

```
function getDetails(name){

    var defered = $q.defer();

    defered.resolve('BobDetails');

    return defered.promise;

}
```

Your callback will be called when the promise is resolved, and as param it will get `'BobDetails'` in this example.